# JQuery booklet problems

Tags: jquery

Good day everyone, I just discovered the JQuery booklet and it looks pretty amazing. However, I cant get it to work. Ive just done all the instructions from  [the official link](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/installation). My HTML is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>New Web Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.booklet.1.3.1/booklet/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.booklet.1.3.1/booklet/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.booklet.1.3.1/booklet/jquery.easing.1.3.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.booklet.1.3.1/booklet/jquery.booklet.1.3.1.min.js"</script>
    <link href="jquery.booklet.1.3.1/booklet/jquery.booklet.1.3.1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libro.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybook">
       <div> 
          <h3>Yay, Page 1!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
          <h3>Yay, Page 2!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
          <h3>Yay, Page 3!</h3>
       </div>
       <div> 
          <h3>Yay, Page 4!</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the js file libro.js is the one who initialize the booklet:

```
$(function()
{  
  $('#mybook').booklet();
});
```

This is what it takes to make it work, but I onle get the  labels one after another and I dont know what else to do... any ideas? Thanx.

Comment: Can you put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: you're missing 4 `>` after your script tags.  not sure if that's a copy/paste error or error in your code

Comment: it works now as it shoul be. thanx for the advice about teh tags, that was driving me crazy. I dont know how the hell that > didnt appear, but it is ok know. Thanx.